# Not Found. The requested URL /print_dokument.php was not found on this server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to display filtered data from my database table named "table1" (criteria: id,date1,date2), using javascript/jquery script. Results must be shown in new window. Everything is ok to the moment when new window is opened. Then, the error occurs as follow:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /mydoc.php was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

My code:

```
function ShowMyDocument(){
    $.get("date_dialog.php",function(data){
        $("#myDiv").html(data); 
        ShowDate('date2'); //set default date to input field "date2" 
        var dat=new Date();
        dat.setDate(1);
        SetMyDate(dat,'date1'); //set default date to input field "date1"
        $("#date1").focus(); //for change date interval
        $("#myDiv").dialog('option','buttons',{
            "Show data": function(){
                var id=document.getElementById('id').innerHTML;
                var d1=mysqldate($("#date1").val());
                var d2=mysqldate($("#date2").val());
                var filterstr=encodeURIComponent("ID="+id+"&DATE1="+d1+"&DATE2="+d2);
                $("#myDiv").dialog("close");
```

This is problematic instruction

```
 var newwin = window.open('mysite.com/mydoc.php?'+filterstr,"_blank");
```

I'm try different options "mydoc.php", full path/mydoc.php and nothing changes.

```
            },
            "Cancel": function(){
                $("#myDiv").dialog("close");
            }
        });
        $("#myDiv").dialog('open');
    });
 }
```

NOTE: PHP file "mydoc.php" 100% exist in root folder of mysite.com.

Comment: Has the user read rights?

Comment: is mydoc.php exists? does the url in the window.open -> is a full url or a relative path?

Comment: file "mydoc.php" 100% exist in root folder of mysite.com.

Comment: @ŠefkijaDuvnjaković You may be sure, but a 404 error is just a 'not found' error. So you have 2 options: 1. The document doesn't exists 2. The path to the document is wrong.

Comment: Open the mydoc.php in your browser (full url with http:// in front) then copy that from your browser address bar...

Answer (score 0):

Opening the new window should contain a full URL. So something like this:

```
var newwin = window.open('http://example.com/mydoc.php?'+filterstr,"_blank");
```

That should work. Or, you can make it shorter on the current domain like this:

```
var newwin = window.open('/mydoc.php?'+filterstr,"_blank");
```

In your case the `mysite.com` is seen as a directory on the current domain, and not as a domain.

Comment: Thank You for Your help, but, everything is the same (I've tried it before)!

Comment: adding information: file "mydoc.php" exist in root folder my subdomain (not domain) ---> http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/mydoc.php

Comment: Clearly something else is wrong. Please see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp Look at the example, play with them, try out different things.